# Анимация кнопки

Tags: java, android

Сделала анимацию кнопки вращение вокруг своей оси в методе setOnTouchListener. А как сделать такую анимацию, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она тряслась? В одной программе увидела такое. Хотела бы и в своей так сделать. В этой программе кнопки с цифрами так трясутся https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gokids.bphone1

rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        final Animation animationRotateCenter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_center);

        imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                view.startAnimation(animationRotateCenter);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Никто не знает как сделать такую анимацию?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй , в 1 примере сдвигаем объект на 10 пикселей , а во 2 повторяем подобное смещение 5 раз:

### 1 (Anim.xml)

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:interpolator="@anim/cycle5"
android:toXDelta="10" />
```

### 2 (Cycle5.xml)

`<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:cycles="5" />`

P.s можно попробовать сделать смещение в верх и вниз и потом зациклить)